# Using a font awesome icon and text in a Datatables column header

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, font-awesome

There is probably an easy answer here but I am trying to put both text and a font awesome icon in the header of a datatable I am trying to update (should go after the the title - 1st line of code). So far I am just getting a blank or a square. Here's a block of code from the map. Anyone have any ideas? Does this have to be done in the CSS instead? Thanks

```
  {title:'enabled' + '<i class="fa fa check green"></i>', class:'enabled small-screen small-screen-2-col',  data:function(row, type, val, meta) {
        var isEnabled = row.enabled || 0;
        if (type=='display') {
          return (isEnabled) ? '<i class="fa fa-check green"></i>' : '' ;
        }
          return isEnabled;
      },
```

Comment: The first classname is wrong. It should be `<i class="fa fa-check green"></i>` instead of `<i class="fa fa check green></i>"`

Comment: Hi @jsrbn thanks but it looks identical to me :)

Comment: The dash between `fa` and `check` is missing

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Hey @jsbrn, it would be nice if you could post your solution as an "Answer", so that @erics15 could accept it and thus close the question. Otherwise it will keep its `unanswered` status which is misleading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first classname is wrong. It should be `<i class="fa fa-check green">` instead of `<i class="fa fa check green></i>`. You forgot the dash between `fa` and `check`